# Internet Explorer Opening Same Page for Different URLs of same website

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, popup, browser-cache

I have an application where i am doing new tab pop-ups in internet explorer(8,10,11) using `window.open(myurl)`
The pop-up triggered by a website contains a URL which is another page of that website. Problem here is that when the pop-up takes place, same webpage opens as the one from where the pop-up is being initiated. 
If i copy the URL from address bar of the pop-up window and close all windows and than open that URL in new window of internet explorer only than my required page opens in the pop-up window/tab.
(Note: Same application works perfectly fine in Mozila Firefox without any issue, but it is clients requirement to run my application in IE)
Following is a method which is doing the pop-up:

```
function handlePhonecallScreenpop(callF, callT, callA, custid, entityN) {

    var extraqs = "cf=" + callF;
    extraqs += "&ct=" + callT;
    extraqs += "&cd=outd";
    extraqs += "&ca=" + callA;
    extraqs += "&cid=" + custid;
    extraqs += "&en=" + entityN;

    var url = webUrl() + "/main.aspx?etn=phonecall&pagetype=entityrecord&extraqs=" + encodeURIComponent(extraqs);
    window.open(url, "callpop");
}
```

Comment: Looks like you need to show some code.

Comment: added in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you aren't setting a target window name. Which means that you're reusing the same target window for EVERY `window.open()` call. Try adding an arg to each of your calls:

```
window.open('firsturl', 'windowA');
```

vs.

```
window.open('secondurl', 'windowB');
```

You should see two different windows.

Comment: @pointer Yeah - you're always targetting the same window name. Try removing the second argument to `window.open(url, "callpop");` or make it different for different kinds of popups.

Comment: is it a IE specific thing? as my pop-up is working perfectly in firefox

Comment: @pointer FF may have different business logic with the tab implementation. In your case, it sounds like it's acting differently, but [mozilla supports the window name argument.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Answer (score 0):

If you change the name to _blank it should always open in a new window.

```
window.open(url, "_blank");
```

Comment: thank you, i have tried this and the result is still the same.